# Fiber cable mixing single mode with multi mode

Tags: cisco, switch, fiber, cable, layer1

Does following scenario work? We have single mode fiber running between two building, but we have MMF patchcord connected to SPF (SFP-10GBase-SR).

```
[SPF]---MMF----[=======SMF======]----MMF---[SPF]
```

I am seeing my interface is flapping but just wanted to make sure it whether it because of mixing fiber mode or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this absolutely is a problem. Don't ever mix different types of cabling. Multimode has a 50 or 62.5 micron core diameter, while single mode fiber typically has a 9 micron core. If you connect two fibers with different core diameters, you'll lose a *lot* of the light going through the connector, resulting in a link flapping or being down.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! i had doubt but better confirm with you guys! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Going from a multimode fiber or a lightsource designed for multimode fiber into single mode fiber will result in a very high loss.

You need to replace your patch cords with single mode ones and your transcievers with LR ones.

Answer (score 1):

No we can not mix single mode and multi mode fiber cables  due to difference core diameter in size